# trying to port eclipse project from mac lap top to windows server

Tags: java, eclipse

I'v been making a simple target card reading server on eclipse, on my mac portable.  I have a windows server set up, which I would like to install it within eclipse and test run it live.

I can't figure out how to move the project over, this is what i did
1. on mac portable selected export, general and archive, saved it as card game.zip.

On my server, I did import from the file menu, deleted general, zip file and selected game.zip.

it got added to my first project, not as a separate project.
I then tried to create a empty project and right click on it, then select import.  My game crd a project files where added to this project.  But when I tried to run it I got a selection does not contain main type error.

There must be a way to do this....

Comment: here is an interesting article about the other way around http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717247/how-to-transfer-eclipse-workspace-and-project-from-windows-to-linux-and-mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're doing everything right up to the import, at which point you want Import > General > **Existing Project into Workspace**. In that dialog, there is an option (at the top) to import from an archive file.