# Android App made on Mac and need to make it work in Windows

Tags: android, windows, eclipse

I have a problem here. Someone gave me an app that have errors and he wants me to fix them. I can't run the app because the app was made on Mac not on Windows. Every time I try to run it I get that error **"Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens"** and when I locate to the file I find this typed to me "Mac OSX" and some wired question marks. I use eclipse.

Comment: I tried and still getting the same error

Comment: First make sure you have the version of the sdk the app is targetted to

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case, I just changed the encoding (Edit->Set enconding), and change it to UTF-8.

Comment: I installed all the sdks and still have problem and I tried the encoding way and still have the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when the project was copied over it wasn't done right. I suggest re copying following the methods detailed in this question

[How to transfer Eclipse workspace and project from Windows to Linux and Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717247/how-to-transfer-eclipse-workspace-and-project-from-windows-to-linux-and-mac)

(its from windows to mac but should work the other way around)