# Trying to export android project

Tags: android

I'm trying to export a android project from my windows computer to a macbook.
When I import the project into the macbook, all the inports have a error that says 
the import (name of inport) cannot be resolved.
I try to inport a java project and it worked fine.
This is how i did it
On windows computer
A. right clicked on project name
B. selected export
c. selected gebral
D select achiv file

To bring it to the mac
A. selected import
B. genrole
c. Existing projects into workspce

Comment: this is eclipse? What specific imports can't be resolved? Sounds like your classpath is wrong, i.e. you are missing some dependencies.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717247/how-to-transfer-eclipse-workspace-and-project-from-windows-to-linux-and-mac