# How to export Eclipse workspace from Windows to Mac OSX

Tags: eclipse, windows, macos

As the title says, how? I know what I can import individual projects but how can I import my entire workspace from Windows to Mac?

I have tried to copy the files into my existing workspace but it presents me with a myriad of weird errors, like stating that my `Scanner` declaration is wrong even though I imported `java.util.*;`

Comment: It will generally be things like the `Installed JREs` settings in the preferences that cause problems. If you are just going to move the workspace once these can be fixed after the move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is extremely frustrating when switching between operating systems. Sadly it is impossible to export the entire workspace without strange errors popping up. The only method that you will be able to use is import single projects into your existing workspace.

Comment: Is there an easier way? I have many projects in my windows workspace and would like to import them all into my new mac

Comment: consider this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717247/how-to-transfer-eclipse-workspace-and-project-from-windows-to-linux-and-mac